# background-size transition doen't work in IE10/11

Tags: internet-explorer-10, transition, background-size

What's wrong with this code? The zoom transition effect doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10 or 11 (OK in other browsers).

```
<div class="image"></div>

.image {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200");
    background-position:center;
    background-size:100%;
    transition: background-size 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-size 1s ease;
    -o-transition: background-size 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: background-size 1s ease;
} 
.image:hover {
     background-size:150%;
}
```

background-size transition should work with IE10/11 as I see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)
Where is my mistake?
[I made a Codepen here](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/ibrzK)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that background-size transition percentage is not supported by IE. Wierd...
So we'll use SCALE instead of Percentage background-size.
Here is the right code:

```
<div class="image-box">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
</div>  

.image-box{
    width:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.image {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200");
    background-position:center;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
} 
.image:hover {
    transform: scale(2);
    -moz-transform: scale(2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    -o-transform: scale(2);
   -ms-transform: scale(2); /* IE 9 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=2, M12=0, M21=0, M22=2, SizingMethod='auto expand')"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=2, M12=0, M21=0, M22=2, SizingMethod='auto expand'); /* IE6 and 7 */ 
}
```

[**And the updated Codepen here**](http://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/ibrzK)