# CSS3 Transition easing in IE10+ not working

Tags: html, css

I've just noticed that the hover easing on something is not working. It does the zoom effect, but it's instant instead of easing in and out. Is there a work around for IE on this?

CSS:

```
.nav-tile {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    height: 130px;
    width: 360px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-size: 130%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    float:left;
}

    .nav-tile:hover {
        transition: transform 3s linear;
        background-size: 100%;
        -moz-transition: all 3s;
        -webkit-transition: all 3s;
        -o-transition: all 3s;
        -ms-transition: all 3s;
        transition: all 3s;
    }
```

Comment: You've defined the the easing timing function property as `linear`.  If you wanted ease...use that.

Comment: Its fine how it is, works fine and how i want just not in IE

Comment: Then I suspect you'll have to demo it but 0.2s isn't very long for "easing" if you 're trying to transition **on** hover. The 3s is for when the hover comes **off**.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm thinking that IE may not support transitioning of `background-size`.. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836158/background-size-transition-doent-work-in-ie10-11

Comment: Yea i was thinking the same, i need ot try and work a solution for it..

Comment: The linked question seems to have a workaround but requires a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to ease in and out, try this instead of using the "linear" property, set the ease to "ease-in-out".

Here is an example of all the easing effects possible in css3.

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

```
.nav-tile:hover {
        transition: transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
```